# installation and test of GTK-fortran on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, cmake, fortran, gtk

I tried to follow the steps here : https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/gtk.html

> We first have to build the Fortran interface library gtk-fortran.
> Create a directory build/, run CMake to output a Makefile, and then
> compile the libraries:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran
$ cd gtk-fortran/
$ mkdir build && cd build/
$ cmake ..
```

Here what happened when I tried to run "cmake .." :
[image: Results of the tuto]

My Fortran compilator has been installed by MSYS (pacman) AND by using MINGW. I can compile and execute my Fortran program from the CMD.

If you have an idea what happened... It will be very helpful. I'm not an expert in the use of those tools but I'll try anything...

Comment: Don't know what CMake used as default in your case and what is used, but have a look at the different possibilitie sof the `-G` option i.e e.g `NMake Makefiles`, `MSYS Makefiles` and `MinGW Makefiles`

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Please *never* upload error messages as pictures or screenshots. Always, really always, copy and paste the text. Please do it, [edit] your question. It is important to have the error message searchable for other people with a similar problems. There are tutorials available if you do not know how to copy text from the windows terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows gtk-fortran instructions](https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki#windows) states that you should generate make files with the command `$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..` (default on MSYS or MINGW is "NMake Makefiles"). It works form the MINGW terminal window. From the CMD window, I don't know.